# The Script says class not derived from MonoBehaviour in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

No matter what script I try to add, it always says the script does not contain a class from UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour. An example script I'm trying to use is this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using System.Collections;
 
public class Wander : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float wanderRadius;
    public float wanderTimer;

    private Transform target;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private float timer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void OnEnable()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        timer = wanderTimer;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer >= wanderTimer)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = RandomNavSphere(transform.position, wanderRadius, -1);
            agent.SetDestination(newPos);
            timer = 0;
        }
    }

    public static Vector3 RandomNavSphere(Vector3 origin, float dist, int layermask)
    {
        Vector3 randDirection = Random.insideUnitSphere * dist;

        randDirection += origin;

        NavMeshHit navHit;

        NavMesh.SamplePosition(randDirection, out navHit, dist, layermask);

        return navHit.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this file named and where is it located in your project?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you change the name of the class or file, but not the other.  Make sure that your class and file name match.  Also make sure the file is in the Assets folder, or a subdirectory of it.